# Can't disable trigger Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I hope you can help me cause it becomes problematic. I inherited database logic which is based on triggers which update rows. Today I set status in one record which caused constant updating in another table and on itself. I can't update and delete record also I can't disable trigger.

I already tried to run

```
LOCK TABLE table IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

to lock the table and delete problematic record

and

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER TR DISABLE';
```

but it's been running for last 30 minutes and nothing happens. If you got any idea how to stop it I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you kill the session that is running the update, or cancel the SQL if you're on 18c+? https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions

Comment: What is your DB version ? Check if there is any lock on the table  and kill the session https://www.support.dbagenesis.com/post/lock-conflict-in-oracle .

Comment: Then talk to your DBA. This is the type issue they exist for.